# Composing Polymer elements without a parent element

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm trying to work out the best way to allow elements to be composed without having to create a host element.  In my example below I have a "client" element that interfaces with an external API to send and receive chat messages, and a "my-conversation" element that serves as the UI.

```
/ Slim
template is="dom-bind"
  twilio-ipm-client token="secret" api="{{client}}"
  my-conversation client="[[client]]"
```

`twilio-api-client` provides a replaceable interface that `my-conversation` can use. At the moment I'm exposing the client API by setting the `api` attribute to itself:

```
# CoffeeScript
Polymer
  is: "twilio-ipm-client"

  properties:
    api:
      type: Object
      notify: true
      value: -> this
```

This let's me do everything I want but with some tricky bits, like I have to call `this.set("api.messages", messages)` for `my-conversation` to receive the correct event.

Composing elements in this way lets me configure them easily, otherwise I would have to set a lot of attributes (not shown here) on the parent only to pass each one down to `twilio-ipm-client`. The parent interface has to expand to deal with the children.

Is there a better way in Polymer?